# How to find out Yocto version

Tags: version, yocto

How to find the current version of Yocto kernel that I am using to build the components. There is a version for poky. But i want to know the Yocto kernel version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- To know the yocto kernel version you are using, just type 
  `bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep "^PV"`
- And to know the kernel you are using, type `bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep "^PN"`

And if you have any kernel you want to know the version, type `bitbake -e <kernel_name> | grep "^PV"`

I hope this will  be helpfull

Answer (score 17):

**How to find out Yocto version?**

Check out this file it gives you full details about Yocto version

> vim $POKY-DIR/meta-poky/conf/distro/poky.conf

You will get info like:

```
DISTRO = "poky"
DISTRO_NAME = "Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"
DISTRO_VERSION = "2.7.2"
DISTRO_CODENAME = "warrior"
SDK_VENDOR = "-pokysdk"
SDK_VERSION = "${@d.getVar('DISTRO_VERSION').replace('snapshot-${DATE}', 'snapshot')}"
.....
.....
```

Now you will know the version you are actually using.

**To find the kernel version you are using:**

> bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep "^PV"

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun  6 2016 14:49:34)
Unknown option argument: "-DIR/meta-poky/conf/distro/poky.conf"
More info with: "vim -h"

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to get this together with some other yocto related information without launching bitbake is doing the following

```
 cat $POKY-DIR/documentation/poky.ent | grep "DISTRO_REL_TAG"
```

**To know DISTRO info**

cat $POKY-DIR/documentation/poky.ent | grep "DISTRO*"

**To know POKY info**

```
cat $POKY-DIR/documentation/poky.ent | grep "POKY*"
```

**To know YOCTO info**

```
cat $POKY-DIR/documentation/poky.ent | grep "YOCTO*"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd poky
grep "DISTRO_" meta-poky/conf/distro/poky.conf
```